# Remove object from array of objects (array1) if array2 does not have the same object key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two array of objects arr1 and arr2.

```
enter code here
const arr1 = [
   {name: 'Jake', age: 17},
   {name: 'Mike', age: 15},
   {name: 'Ryan', age: 18},
 ];

 const arr2 = [
   {name: 'Milo', age: 17},
   {name: 'Rem', age: 18},
   {name: 'Oliver', age: 19},
 ];
```

I want to remove objects in arr1 that does not have key value that arr2 has. I tried this, but no success:

```
const arr3 = this.arr1.filter(x => {
   let z = this.arr2.find(y => y.age== x.age)
   if (z) {
      return x;
   }
});
```

My expected array is this:

```
array3 = [
  {name: 'Jake', age: 17},
  {name: 'Ryan', age: 18},
];
```

Comment: remove `this` keyword keeping the same code while calculating const arr3

Comment: As pointed out in the deleted post, your code actually works. ( if you remove the `this` or add it everywhere appropriate )  So if the `this` references aren't the issue, we cannot find an issue with the code and need to see more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Array.`some` methods returns a boolean value which it slightly more appropriate. However `find` works too since non-null/undefined are treated as thruthy. If you arrays are truly in a class, then:

```
const arr3 = this.arr1.filter(x => this.arr2.some(y => y.age === x.age));
```

Otherwise need to remove `this`:

```
const arr3 =arr1.filter(x => arr2.some(y => y.age === x.age));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove `this` from the variables. Also, you can shorten the return statements like this:

```js
const arr1 = [
   {name: 'Jake', age: 17},
   {name: 'Mike', age: 15},
   {name: 'Ryan', age: 18},
 ];

 const arr2 = [
   {name: 'Milo', age: 17},
   {name: 'Rem', age: 18},
   {name: 'Oliver', age: 19},
 ];

const arr3 = arr1.filter(x => z = arr2.find(y => y.age== x.age));

console.log(arr3)
```

**However, if you want keep `this`** you can declare the variables using `var` and then `this.arr` will be referring to `window.arr` and the code will still work as var creates a property on the global object while const or let do not:

```js
    var arr1 = [
       {name: 'Jake', age: 17},
       {name: 'Mike', age: 15},
       {name: 'Ryan', age: 18},
     ];

     var arr2 = [
       {name: 'Milo', age: 17},
       {name: 'Rem', age: 18},
       {name: 'Oliver', age: 19},
     ];

    const arr3 = this.arr1.filter(x => z = this.arr2.find(y => y.age== x.age));

    console.log(arr3)
```